# Eclipse won't acknowledge print margin column setting

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse 4.6.2, I tried to put a print margin indicator line at 80 characters using Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> [Checkbox] Show Print Margin. However, no matter what value I put in the Print Margin Column box, the line stays at column 120.

I'm certain the line I'm looking at is the Print Margin, because I can change its color in the same Preferences page. I've hit Apply and restarted Eclipse, but no luck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Welcome to bug [468307](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468307), where your maximum line wrapping length is what matters.

---

2020-12-04:

I'm on eclipse-CDT version 2020-06 and the bug is still not fixed IMO.

- the workaround is to modify the "Maximum line width" for your language
- for example in C++: File --> Window --> Preferences --> C/C++ --> Code Style --> Formatter --> Edit --> Line Wrapping --> Line width and indentation levels --> click the "Maximum line width" textedit widget and modify the value to 80 or 100 or your desired value --> click "ok" (if your "ok" button is gray then read [gotcha-1] footnote)
- other languages like Java require modifying the same "Maximum line width" but getting there might be different in the GUI

[gotcha-1]
gotcha: if the "ok" button is gray then you have to edit the "Profile name:" because it does not let you override a default profile.

Comment: The bug is marked fixed in 4.5, but I still found no way to change the column in 4.7.  Setting `Text Editors -> Print Margin` still does nothing (so the behavior is still confusing and the bug as named isn't fixed), but neither does `Formatter -> Edit... (or Project Specific Settings) -> Line Wrapping -> Maximum line width`.

Comment: The `Version` field in Bugzilla is the version it's reported against, not the one in which it is fixed. The `Target Milestone` field is the one you're looking for, and the 4.x releases have lined up with the year so far (4.2=2012, 4.3=2013, etc.), so it's only very recently been fixed for the upcoming 2018 release.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, thank you.  I presume "fixed" means that (once the fix is delivered) it will change when I change the `Print Margin` preference.  For now though, did your answer mean that the location where it's drawn changes for you when you change the `Max line width`?  I'm not seeing that effect.

Comment: I'm not sure about versions older than the milestone where they say it's fixed. Running that milestone as part of shutting down our WTP's release, the print margin value seems to be behaving in the least surprising way.

Comment: @trevor-boyd-smith In which editor are you not seeing this as fixed? It's correct in the JSP and Java editors.

Comment: @nitind eclipse-cdt version 2020-06.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Looks like that might be a separate issue specific to CDT and the C/C++ Editor, rather than the one I pointed to that generically affected all text editors.

Answer (score 1):

For the other newcomers here, the line wrapping bug mentioned by @nitind can be solved at:

Preferences -> Language (i.e. C/C++, Java) -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit (or create new of your own) -> Line Wrapping (tab) -> Maximum line width